# Как задать фон объекту при использовании Color input

Tags: html, jquery

Как передать значение выбранного цвета?
Нужно чтобы цвет фона у `<p>` становился таким, какой выбрали в палитре `input color` и оставался таким после f5.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Цвет</title>
        </head>
        <body>
<div id="windiw3">
            <p  class="color_input">Январь <input class="color_input" type="color" name="bg" value="#88c1ff">
            <p  class="color_input">Февраль <input class="color_input" type="color" name="bg" value="#5eff37">
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Используйте js/jquery для обработки ввода, localStorage для сохранения/загрузки цветов, что вам конкретно не понятно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**StackOverflow не поддерживает localStorage**
Испытайте код на своём пк

```js
const changeColor = document.querySelectorAll('.change_color');
  const changeFont = document.querySelectorAll('.change_font');

  const colorTextInput = document.getElementById('change_text');
  const colorFontInput = document.getElementById('change_font');

  const defaultText = '#000', defaultFont = 'transparent';

  colorTextInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    colorChangeForText(this.value);
  })

  colorFontInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    colorChangeForFont(this.value);
  })

  function colorChangeForText(color) {
    localStorage.setItem('text', color);

    updateColor();
  }

  function colorChangeForFont(color) {
    localStorage.setItem('font', color);

    updateColor();
  }

  function updateColor() {
    let textColor = localStorage.getItem('text') == null ? defaultText : localStorage.getItem('text');
    let fontColor = localStorage.getItem('font') == null ? defaultFont : localStorage.getItem('font');;

    for (let i = 0; i < changeColor.length; i++) {
      changeColor[i].style.color = textColor;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < changeFont.length; i++) {
      changeFont[i].style.backgroundColor = fontColor;
    }
  }

  updateColor();
```

```html
<div id="windiw3">
  <p class="color_input change_color">
    Цвет<input class="color_input" type="color" name="bg" value="#88c1ff" id="change_text">
  </p>
  <p class="color_input change_font">
    Фон <input class="color_input" type="color" name="bg" value="#5eff37" id="change_font">
  </p>

  <p class="change_font change_color">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis necessitatibus, excepturi et soluta exercitationem quia fugit nobis quo vero distinctio incidunt voluptate repudiandae ullam ducimus maxime voluptatum dolorem magnam non?
  </p>

  <button onclick="localStorage.clear();updateColor()">Очистить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время! К сожалению, есть какая-то ошибка, способ не работает.
Текст ошибки - Cannot read properties of null

Comment: @Polo ну не знаю, у меня всё работает, может какой-то симбол изменили?

Comment: И правда. Спасибо большое, все работает!
Проблема решилась добавлением всего кода в функцию window.onload=function(){}